# jQuery selectors don't work for siblings?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

i have a multilevel menu with anchor-tags in it.
My problem is to get the jQuery selectors to work properly.

Working code:

```
$(this)
    .closest('li')
    .siblings('li.open')
    .children('a')
    .children('i')
    .toggleClass('class1')
    .toggleClass('class2');
```

What it should be:

```
$(this)
    .closest('li')
    .siblings('li.open > a > i')
    .toggleClass('class1')
    .toggleClass('class2');
```

But not even this works:

```
$(this)
    .closest('li')
    .siblings('li.open a i')
    .toggleClass('class1')
    .toggleClass('class2');
```

What i want to do in text-form:
The onClick event targets an anchor tag. I want the i-Tags in the anchors of the siblings of his parent LI - god that sounds aweful - to toggle two different classes.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="open">
        <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><i class="class1"></i>Label</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This question would make a little more sense if we were able to see your HTML.

Comment: i added it. It's a simple list. With more lists nested in it. As you can see, the second top-level LI has the class "open".
If i click the first top-level LI's anchor, i need the li.open's anchor-tags i-tag (sorry for such phrasing) to toggle the classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason it won't work is because

```
('li.open > a > i')
```

is not a sibling of

```
$(this).closest('li')
```

The sibling of the li is another li.

You could try

```
$(this).closest('li').sibling('li.open').find('a > i').toggleClass('blah');
```

Why can't you use the first piece of code you posted?

Comment: i can use it. It just doesn't look pretty and i wanted to know why it doesn't work.
Thanks for you explanation.

Comment: But i can't use find() because the LI has more children than just the anchor tag. For example other lists including more anchor tags. It's a multi-level menu

Comment: Ah ok, yeah in that case the code you first posted is probably the best way to do it